# How can I change the app for managing root access from SuperSU to Superuser?

Tags: rooting, superuser

I used a rooting package on my Galaxy S4 which installed SuperSU. Howvever, I preferred to use SuperUser, so I removed SuperSU and installed SuperUser.

Now the apps that normally request root do not seem to do it anymore, and also cease to function correctly.

How can I make my newly installed SuperUser App into the default root manager?

Answer (score -1):

1. open settings in Super SU.
2. go to cleanup section.
3. switch Superuser app.

Comment: weird enough that clean for switch options removes both superSU and superuser, after reinstalling superuser and launching it, it still complains about old binary and cant install new one.